# Conversion required for two little endian machine

Tags: c, endianness

I was been asked in an interview question about "Does the conversion (little to big endian & vice versa) required for data which have to be transfer between two little endian machine"

As far as i know the little endian store lowest byte at lowest address and big endian stores higher byte at lowest address. I am not sure for data transfer between two machine how it happens?

Anyone have any idea on this.

Thanks

Comment: I think if I had been asked something like this in an interviewer, I'd have asked the interviewer to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Functions like `htons`, `htonl`, `ntohs` and `ntohl` can convert little endian to network order (big-endian) and vice versa. Network protocols require data to be converted to big-endian first, and are then converted back to little endian if that is the host byte order.

Answer (score 0):

The convention is to transfer numerics over the network in big-endian format.
In general, you should not make any assumptions about destination machine platform.
This way two machines can understand each other, even if they use different formats for storing numerics internally.